# How to implement localization in angular element?

Tags: angular, firebase

I am trying to add a angular element to a site that supports multiple languages and would like to use localization in my angular element as well. Traditionally i18n uses asset files for storing translation values however angular element cannot use these since it gets compressed into a single js file. Is there any way, like using firebase in some smart way, to have localization in angular element?

Comment: Just send the traslated text as input.

Comment: @ritaj really not what I am looking for, I don't want to have the user make a million inputs